# install ipadic on Ubuntu 16.04 for mecab Japanese tokenizer

Tags: installation, tokenize, mecab

I am trying to install mecab and the ipadic dictionary as outlined here: http://taku910.github.io/mecab/#install-unix

I was able to successfully download mecab and install it and succesfully downloaded ipadic but get stuck on the second line of instruction below:

```
% tar zxfv mecab-ipadic-2.7.0-XXXX.tar.gz
% mecab-ipadic-2.7.0-XXXX
% ./configure
% make
% su
# make install
```

I am getting:

`mecab-ipadic-2.7.0-20070801: command not found`

I tried `chmod -x` on it and then tried it but same result.

Any help is appreciated.

Edit (result of cat /etc/mecabrc)

```
;
; Configuration file of MeCab
;
; $Id: mecabrc.in,v 1.3 2006/05/29 15:36:08 taku-ku Exp $;
;
dicdir = /usr/local/lib/mecab/dic/mecab-ipadic-neologd

; userdic = /home/foo/bar/user.dic

; output-format-type = wakati
; input-buffer-size = 8192

; node-format = %m\n
; bos-format = %S\n
; eos-format = EOS\n
```

Comment: Just curious, does `apt-get install mecab-ipadic` work?

Comment: Also, I think you need a `cd`, i.e., `cd mecab-ipadic-2.7.0-XXXX`, after you untar and before you run `./configure`.

Comment: @AhmedFasih Hey! Great advice, I couldn't cd so I did `sudo su` and then could `cd` and `./configure`.  Going to test it to see if the dictionary works now.

Comment: Very weird, you certainly don't need to be root to just `cd` and run the configure script, did you maybe download or untar as root? But anyway, sounds like you sorted it out, feel free to answer your own question and accept. Happy tokenizing!

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work properly.  It is in Japanese but I have a new posting here:  https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/45465/mecab%E3%81%8C%E6%96%87%E5%AD%97%E5%8C%96%E3%81%91%E3%81%A8unicodedecodeerror%E3%81%8C%E7%99%BA%E7%94%9F

Comment: I have moved this discussion to the Japanese Stackoverflow: https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/45465/mecab%E3%81%8C%E6%96%87%E5%AD%97%E5%8C%96%E3%81%91%E3%81%A8unicodedecodeerror%E3%81%8C%E7%99%BA%E7%94%9F I will either delete this question or translate the answer if I get one over there.

Comment: Ok. Since you have root, is there a reason you can't do `apt-get install mecab-ipadic`?

Comment: @AhmedFasih I think it did but am following the other thread now.  If you need help reading it, let me know.  Othewise I'm going to close this in 8 hours.

Comment: Excellent, glad Japanese StackOverflow helped you figure it out.

Comment: Instead of posting a link to a post on the Japanese site, which few users here would be able to read, please post an answer here that explains how you solved the problem. (Please note that it is not appropriate to post an English translation on the Japanese site or a Japanese translation here; both would be considered noise.)

Comment: @EdCottrell I am piecing together advice received on the JA and EN sites so what should I do?  Delete this quetion altogether here?

Comment: @hockeymonkey33 Ideally, you could post a complete answer in English here and a complete answer in Japanese on that site. That way, users of both sites can benefit.

Comment: @EdCottrell I received some help below so hopefully I can confirm that soon.  Will do though regarding your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason to compile from source on Ubuntu 16.04

Simple do:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt install mecab mecab-ipadic-utf8
```

Then test it with

```
$ echo "日本語です" | mecab
日本  ニッポン    ニッポン    日本  名詞-固有名詞-地名-国        
語   ゴ   ゴ   語   名詞-普通名詞-一般      
です  デス  デス  です  助動詞 助動詞-デス  終止形-一般
EOS
```

If things don't work, you may need to link `/etc/mecabrc` to the installed dictionary by setting `dicdir=SOMEPATH_TO_IPADIC`

Comment: I have `dicdir = /usr/lib/mecab/dic/mecab-ipadic-neologd` and getting garbled characters, ie. `�です ����,����,*,*,*,*,*`  How can I find my `SOMEPATH_TO_IPADIC`?

Comment: I followed instructions here:  https://qiita.com/ekzemplaro/items/c98c7f6698f130b55d53 and set `dicdir = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mecab/dic/mecab-ipadic-neologd` as shown a third of the way down.

Comment: when I designate the dictionary with `mecab -d /var/lib/mecab/dic/ipadic-utf8` I get normal output, not garbled.  So do I set `dicdir` in `/etc/mecabrc` to `/var/lib/mecab/dic/ipadic-utf8`?  Actually I just tried this and it didn't work.

Comment: Can you `cat /etc/mecabrc`? And paste the appropriate line. There is no reason for it not to work if you set the dictionary path as shown. You could also confirm that mecabrc is being loaded with the `--rcfile=PATH_TO_MECABRC` option

Comment: `mecab -r /etc/mecabrc` also works but I wish I could make some changes so that I can run `mecab` without the suffixes.

Comment: This is probably as close to an answer I'll get for now please try adding the various suffixes in the comments above.

Comment: There's your issue. What you have in your question is not the same as you have when you use the `-d` flag. You need `dicdir = /var/lib/mecab/dic/ipadic-utf8` in mecabrc and then it should work.

Comment: `;
; Configuration file of MeCab
;
; $Id: mecabrc.in,v 1.3 2006/05/29 15:36:08 taku-ku Exp $;
;
dicdir = /var/lib/mecab/dic/ipadic-utf8

; userdic = /home/foo/bar/user.dic

; output-format-type = wakati
; input-buffer-size = 8192

; node-format = %m\n
; bos-format = %S\n
; eos-format = EOS\n`

Comment: I've set it per above but it still is garbled so I think my installation has a problem?  It only works with the `-d` flag.